# How can i upload/use my client script in suitescript NetSuite

Tags: netsuite

Can somebody explain to my how can i use or upload my client script in suitescript creating a form in netsuite? Appreciate the help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not clear. You want to upload a client script that would create a form?

First, do you want to upload javascript/suitescript file? if yes then you should follow what Jo O posted earlier.

Second, you mean your client script will create form? I don't think it is possible because only suitelet can create a form.

Third, you mean to say that you want a client script attached to a form? If yes there are two ways to do it, First you can customize your form and put your client script on the Custom Code tab. Second is to create a client script record and do not deploy it to any record take note of the script ID and you can use the setScript method to set/attach the script on the nlobjForm object on before record load of user event script or on the suitelet.

Answer (score 1):

This is from SuiteAnswers # 23388.

Assuming you're using the Eclipse IDE with the SuiteScript Add-in, first make sure that you have your NetSuite accounts setup in the IDE:

1.In SuiteCloud IDE, set your master password by going to NetSuite > Master Password > Set Master Password.

2.Add your NetSuite accounts by going to NetSuite > Accounts and clicking Add.

After you have the script file ready:
3.Next, right-click in the SuiteCloud IDE editor area and then go to NetSuite > Upload File in Editor. The Upload File in Editor window opens. Wait for the progress bar to complete. The Upload File in Editor window closes upon completion.

Verify Your Script Upload 
4.Right-click in the editor area and then go to NetSuite > Log in to Project Account. A browser loads with your NetSuite account logged in.

5.In NetSuite, go to Documents > Files > File Cabinet. The File Cabinet Folders page of your NetSuite account loads.

6.Navigate to the SuiteScripts directory and check your file in the subdirectory that matches your project name.

You then need to create a custom form that will link in this code.
7.In NetSuite, go to Customization > Scripting > Scripts > New. The Select Type page loads.

8.In the Type list, click Suitelet. (assuming your code is a suitelet)

9.In the Name field, enter a valid name (example: GettingStarted_SS_HelloWorld).

10.In the ID field, enter a name that begins with an underscore (example: _gs_ss_helloworld).

11.In the Scripts subtab, select your *.js file in the Script File dropdown list.

12.In the Function field, enter the function name that you wrote. Use the exact case and do not use the parentheses.

13.Hover over the dropdown arrow on the Save button, and then click Save and Deploy. The New Script Deployment page loads.

14.In the Title field, enter the Name value from step 9.

15.In the ID field, enter the ID value from step 10.

16.In the Status dropdown list, select Testing.

17.Click the Links subtab.

18.In the Center dropdown list, select Classic Center (or whichever Center is appropriate).

19.In the Section dropdown list, select the menu where you want this to appear (example: Setup).

20.In the Category dropdown list, select the submenu on the menu where you want this to appear (example: Custom).

21.In the Label field, enter the exact item on the menu that you want the user to select (example: Getting Started).

22.Click Add.

23.Click Save.

Test Your Script 
24.In NetSuite, go to the menu, submenu, and item specified in steps 19, 20, and 20 (example: Setup > Custom > Getting Started). The page you just created should load.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a Suitelet with a form and then create url using N/url and open it using https or nlExtOpenWindow from client side.